# How to hide Salesforce standard search bar and bar tab on top in Lightning experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, search, header-bar

I am trying to hide Salesforce standard search from custom Vf page in Classic and Lightning experience.

By using below, i can able to hide in classic view but not in lightning experience.

```
 apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false"
```

Any ideas how to hide standard search and object tabs from lightning experience?

Comment: Where are you placing the vf page in lightning experience ? Tabs or related list ?

Comment: The VF page is a tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated on [Lightning Experience FAQ](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Experience_FAQ):

> You will no longer have the option to hide the header or sidebar. The Salesforce Classic header and sidebar will always be suppressed in Lightning Experience. The Lightning Experience header and left nav menu will always show. No code changes are required for this behavior. Viewing the VF page in Salesforce Classic will behave the same as it does today.